# sie ..... hat .... kein Geld nicht

Tags: meaning, negation

Was für eine grammatische Konstruktion ist es: "kein Geld nicht"? Bedeutet das nur, dass die Tante kein Geld hat? Warum sind hier zwei Verneinungen in einem Satz?

Die Tante hat gesagt, sie muss sehr sparsam sein, weil sie so wenig Pension hat und kein Geld nicht.

Comment: Da gibt's doch was bei Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelte_Verneinung

Comment: Bist du sicher, dass du richtig zitiert hast?

Comment: Ja, ich bin sicher. Das ist ein Zitet aus der Erzählug "Tante Frieda" von Ludwig Thoma.

Comment: Das wäre ziemlich alt (so um 1900 herum), und ein wenig bayrisch.

Comment: Das ist extrem verbreitet in deutschen Dialekten mit böhmisch / tschechischem Einfluß: Der "brave Soldat Schwejk" hatte das als Markenzeichen.

Comment: The additional information should be in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Doppelte Verneinung wie im Zitat

> Die Tante sagt, sie hat kein Geld nicht

ist typische für dialektale Formen des Deutschen. Der Autor Ludwig Thoma verwendet in seinen Geschichten solche Formen absichtsvoll, um ein regionales (hier: bayerisches) Flair zu erzeugen.

Auch heute könnte man in Bayern jemanden sagen hören, der kein Geld hat:

> I hob koa Göid nöd

(Ich habe kein Geld nicht), was standardsprachlich mit "Ich habe kein Geld" übersetzt werden müsste.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelte_Verneinung) erklärt ziemlich klar: "Die doppelte Verneinung findet in lyrischen Texten als Bekräftigung Verwendung."

Die Verneinung wird damit verstärkt.

Während es in anderen [Sprachen](http://deacademic.com/dic.nsf/dewiki/347337/Doppelte#Doppelte_Verneinung_in_anderen_Sprachen) standardmäßig zur Bekräftigung benutzt wird, kommt es im Deutschen neben der Klassischen Literatur nur noch in wenigen Dialekten vor. Ich kenne es selbst von starkem Berlinern. Inwiefern es im Plattdeutschen noch aktiv verwendet wird kann ich nicht sagen.

Das Konstrukt der Verstärkung kommt daher, daß man einmal das Objekt (kein Geld) und dann nochmal das Partizip negiert (nicht haben). Ist eigentlich eine interessante Konstruktion, wird aber immer seltener verwendet.

Answer (score 2):

It's like saying 'she ain't got no money'. Is probably ok in some dialects but non-existent in others where there's no double negation.